# What's the difference between SysPrep and NewSid?

Tags: virtual-pc

I'm setting up some Virtual PC images.  I want to customize the machine with some pre-installed tools and then use this as a base for creating new machines.

What's the best practice for prepping the machine for use?

Should I use SysPrep or NewSid?  When's the appropriate time for use and the contrast between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sysprep includes the functionality of NewSID.  It 'preps' the WIndows installation for imaging by stripping machine-specific things like the Machine name and SID from the installation.  If you were not using Sysprep, you definitely would need to run a program like NewSID on each PC after deployment of the image.

-- Steve Olson

Comment: In addition to doing the sorts of things that NewSid does, sysprep also resets/updates a number of other pieces of state in the installation to prepare for duplication/imaging.  (Not updating this state can cause unexpected errors after deployment.)  In general, it's a good idea to use sysprep...

Answer (score 0):

NewSid seems to have some issues. I am aware that with Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 and with technologies that built on them (Sharepoint Server 2007, Project Server 2007), you can run into issues outlined here:

[NewSID and SharePoint 2007](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=6260)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers already posted here it is also important to note that SysPrep is fully supported by Microsoft, while NewSID isn't.